# problem with deformation of curve modifier

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

i was want to make cylinder with holes i make this plane [image]

and then i add array and curve modifier as shown :
[image]

you can see the mesh is not connected even when merge is enabled
so i apply the array modifier and then merge them manually in edit mode

but the problem when i want to change the size of the mesh by scale the curve
the merged vertices that i connected them (merge) deformed in strange way unlike other vertices    :
[image]

so i know it should scale before apply array but i just want to know why this happen  it just  a merge ??

Comment: Merge operator of Array modifier is merging segments generated by Array. What you see on second image is start / end part of Array strip. When you disable Curve modifier you can see those parts are on opposite side of mesh, so there is not a reason to expect merging those ends :) Curve modifier is deforming mesh after Array is done.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the order of events.

- 'First and Last' merging in the *Array* modifier doesn't work because the *Curve* hasn't happened yet. (It's only really useful when the rotation is performed *in* the array)
- Modifiers operate on the mesh as handed to them by the stack. But edits on the mesh happen before *any* modifiers. So you have merged vertices on the strip in its uncurled state. If you switch off the *Curve* modifier, you can see:

[image]

One way of merging the ends of a cyclically-deformed array is to put a *Weld* modifier below the *Curve*. Then you can leave all your modifiers live.

Comment: @vklidu .. Oops, sorry, I crashed your answer.

Comment: +1 Don't worry. You are just faster and with advanced answer :) ... I started to experiment, because I was surprised blender even knows what to do with this looped mesh :) Than I realised it merged start-end just because it is single face (by adding vertical loops it became curved to the right place, seen in edit mode without curve modifier).